# Move postgresql database from one server to another without dump file

Tags: postgresql

is it possible copy pg_data from docker and paste new database server in location /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/ ? I have tried and getting error

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

how can I solve this problem? Via dump file can't restoring, I need exactly through copy paste pg_data

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) for this:

> pg_basebackup makes an exact copy of the database cluster's files,
> while making sure the server is put into and out of backup mode
> automatically.